# CiviCRM "database looks to have been partially upgraded"

Tags: drupal-7, upgrade, civicrm

I recently upgraded both Drupal and CiviCRM to the latest versions. Drupal works fine, and so does Civi except when I move to the Civi menu, I get a message that says "Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded. You may want to reload the database with the backup and try the upgrade process again." This happened earlier and reloading the most recent backup didn't help. We had to go back quite a ways before we found one that did, then had to reload a lot of data from .CSV files and by hand. I'd rather not go through with that again. 
One thing we found when comparing the development site on my WAMP desktop (which was a new install that works well) with the one on my ISP's server is that the server version contained two MyISam-format files from, or generated by, CiviCase where Civi wants to see InnoDB-format files. My ISP, far more knowlegable than I am about MySQL, converted these two files two InnoDB and the problem remains. This leaves me with two questions:

- could the MyISam files be the source of the "incomplete upgrade"? and
- is there some way to reset a flag that tells Civi that the database is incomplete or to run the database check manually?

Thanks for any help. Civi seems to work OK as is, but the error message will be disturbing to my end users.

Answer (score 0):

That message happens when you have begun the CiviCRM database upgrade but it hasn't finished.  CiviCRM edits the version number in the civicrm_domain table to flag that you're in the middle of an upgrade, and when the upgrade completes, it should remove that.

The simple way to remove the message is to go edit that in the database, but it gets set there for a reason: your database upgrade never completed.

1. You should restore everything to the last version where it all was working--restore both the code and the database.  Play around for a bit and make sure nothing funny is happening.
2. Run a normal CiviCRM upgrade, replacing the files and running the upgrade script.  Take note of *anything* that seems funny when the upgrade script runs.  You might try doing a minor upgrade--just a point release--simply to be sure that any upgrade is working fine.
3. At this point, you should either have no problems or a much more detailed problem.

**Finally, please note that there is now a [CiviCRM-specific StackExchange site](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/), which is where you'll find the most CiviCRM experts to answer your questions.**

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I'm going to explore downloading all the Contacts and Membership data (easy) and the Activities and Events data (?) because much has been added since the last successful backup. Then I think I will do a clean install, in a separate database, and upload the downloads.

Comment: And thanks for the pointer to the proper StackExchange site. I thought that was what I was using.